# как прочитать xml с конца?

Tags: php, xml

Всем доброго времени.
парсю xml файл:

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.vesti.ru/vesti.rss');
```

Прерываюсь так:

```
$count=10;
foreach ( $xml->channel->item as $key => $item)  
{
 ... код ...
    $i++;
    if($i == $count) break;
}
```

Но вот получается, что в файле записей около 50 (и допустим вариируется той стороной) и получается я получаю лишь самые первые, т.е. "старые" 10.
А как реализовать чтение его (xml-файла) с конца?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $key => $item) {
    if ($i < 40) {
        continue;
    }
    if ($i > 50) {
        break;
    }
    // код
}
```

Comment: Так... Т.е. всегда надо знать точное число записей в xml?
А если первоисточник изменит в одностороннем порядке количество записей?
Хотя идея выглядит рабочей, при условии, что количество это константа.

Answer (score 1):

Немного модернизировал код от @Etki:

```
$count=10;
$count_news=0;

foreach ( $xml->channel->item as $key => $item)  
  {
    $count_news++;   
  }

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $key => $item) {
  $i++;
  if ($i <= ($count_news-$count))
  {
    continue;
  }
  else
  {
    [тут делаем свои дела]
    if($i == $count_news) break;
  }
}
```